# Is it possible to delete a completed transaction from your wallet history?

Tags: go-ethereum

Is it possible to get rid of a completed transaction?

Comment: What wallet are you using? Most wallets do not provide a ways to edit the list of past transactions. In any case you cannot delete completed transactions from the blockchain.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to delete a transaction from the blockchain.

Depending on the wallet interface you are using (MyCrypto, Metamask, etc.), you *may* be able to hide transactions, but the transaction will always exist on the blockchain.